# Sequence words with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I search the sequence:

> nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] más[ADV+comp+CIRC] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION]

and

> nunca más compraré

My script:

```
corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] 
otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] 
más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION]"

part1 = re.findall(r"(\w+)\[ADV\+NEG.*?\]", corpus)
part2 = re.findall(r"(\w+)\[ADV+comp+PADV.*?\]", corpus)
part3 = re.findall(r"(\w+)\[V\+H_PREDICAT.*?\]", corpus)
print(part1 + part2 + part3)
```

Result:

> []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the searched substrings are in arbitrary order - use the following: `re.findall()` approach:

```
corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] \
otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] \
más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION]"

result = ' '.join(i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(\w+)\[[^][]*(AD|V)\+[^][]*\]', corpus, re.M | re.UNICODE))
print(result)
```

The output:

```
nunca más compraré
```

---

*regex pattern* explanation:

- `(\w+)` - match a word(alphanumeric sequence) (for ex. `nunca`). Placed into the first captured group `(...)`
- `\[` - match opening square bracket `[` literally
- `[^][]*` - match one or many characters except square brackets `][`
- `(AD|V)` - alternation group, match either `AD` or `V` key
- `\]` - match closing square bracket `]` literally

for ex. `\[[^][]*(AD|V)\+[^][]*\]` will match `[ADV+NEG+CIRC]`

**----------**

If the order of sequences is strict - use `re.sub()` function instead `re.findall()` to remove all parenthetical sequences:

```
corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] \
otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] \
más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION]"

result = re.sub(r'\[[^][]+\]', '', corpus, re.M | re.UNICODE)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
Me temo que buscare otras opciones esta nunca más compraré
```

---

To extract the last 3 words:

```
print(' '.join(result.split()[-3:]))    # nunca más compraré
```

Comment: @pitanga, you may also check my `re.findall` approach

Comment: thanks a lot!!! Can I take advantage and ask you something else? If the sequence is not at the end of the string, how could I find it?

Comment: @pitanga, that's what my `re.findall` approach does

Comment: Sorry, you said that I duplicated this question. You are so intelligent and so experienced that your regex is too advanced for me and I could not understand it. I just want to understand rather than just copy. Thank you and I'm sorry for the duplicate answer.

Comment: @pitanga, ok, see my explanation